# ScriptResource.axd (Html Extender) giving error in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptresource.axd

I have used asp:toolkitscriptmanager in many of my web forms, but in one of my web form i am getting scriptresource.axd error. [image: check image for error]

I have 3 cascading drop downs in my form, when i select value in one drop down the drop down does not do post back. and i got a this error in browser console. the form works fine in other browsers but in chrome it throws error. I have no idea why this is happening, I have searched a lot about this issue but could not find any answer. If someone having problem to understand my issue i will try to clarify but need your help and suggestion.

I have also tried a solution found on google to create a js file and write a code to bypass webkit , but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. Actually the issue is coming by  html extender editor i have used in my form.
So all do is replace the asp html extender to ck editor and it works.
Hope this will help someone.